# How to show that Bernstein set is not Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory

A [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) is a subset of the real line that meets every uncountable closed subset of the real line but that contains none of them. (They can be easily generalized to $\mathbb R^n$, but for the sake of simplicity we might stick with $\mathbb R$.) See also this post for some more details: [What's application of Bernstein Set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169714) (A proof of existence of Bernstein sets is given there - it is based on transfinite induction and well-ordering theorem. Also various properties of Bernstein sets are mentioned there, including the fact that existence of Bernstein sets cannot be shown in ZF.)

My questions are:

- How can we show that a Bernstein set is not Lebesgue measurable?
- Can these proofs be generalized to other measures?

By the latter I mean whether something like this can be said about some of the proofs: "We have shown that Bernstein set is not Lebesgue measurable. But the same proof works for any translation-invariant measure such that all closed sets are measurable and bounded sets have finite measure." (This is just a hypothetical example to make a bit clearer what I mean by the second question.)

---

When I was thinking about this problem, I thought that one way to go would be using [regularity of Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure). Let $B$ be a Bernstein set. If $C\subseteq B$ is compact, then it has to be countable and thus $\mu(C)=0$. Similarly, if $B\subseteq U$ then $B$ does not intersect the closed set $\mathbb R\setminus U$, hence $U$ is complement of countable set and $\mu(U)=\infty$. So from regularity of Lebesgue measure we get that $B$ is not measurable.

I have considered also posting my attempt sketched in the previous paragraph as an answer. But I decided not to do so - maybe somebody who knows more about this will be able to expand on this or add some other related results and useful observations.

Comment: Well, the outer measure of a Bernstein set is full. The inner measure, as you point out, is null.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not sure whether the rhyme was intentional or just a lucky accident, but this reminded my of Yemon Choi's poems on [meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/599/do-we-have-an-unofficial-quota-on-how-many-old-questions-one-should-bump-for-min/781#comment3623_604)/[tea](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1374/must-we-raise-the-dead-for-umlauts-sake/).

Comment: While I am no Fezzik, I do enjoy the occasional rhyme (and probably more than just some other next guy). The one above was by pure luck, not unlike a chicken and duck. (Sorry, I've been marathoning Friends recently...)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: They don't actually rhyme.  "Full" has the vowel of "foot" and "null" has the vowel of "nut".

Comment: @EricWofsey Well, you're certainly right. That's the problem when I try to discuss rhymes or puns in English. (I am not a native English speaker.)

Comment: @Eric: If your pronunciation is influenced by German, you will make full and null rhyme quite naturally... :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one quick way of doing this: The complement of a Bernstein set is a Bernstein set.

Now, it is enough to argue that a Bernstein set has inner measure $0$. That implies that also its complement—another Bernstein set—has inner measure $0$, and that is certainly impossible if the sets were measurable.

And indeed, every compact subset of a Bernstein set is countable. So the inner measure is $0$.

Comment: how can we prove that the complement of a Bernstein
set is Bernstein?

Comment: Well. Can the Complement contain a perfect subset? Can it be disjoint from one?

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem**: Any measurable subset of a Bernstein set must be a null set.

Proof: Let $A$ be a  measurable subset of a Bernstein set $B$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists a closed set $F \subset A$  such
that
$$\lambda (A \setminus F) < \epsilon$$

$F\subset A\subset B$ implies $F\cap B^c=\emptyset $.

Hence $F$ must be countable.

Then $\lambda(A)=\lambda(F)+\lambda(A\setminus F)<\epsilon$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary,$\lambda(A) =0$

---

Claim: Bernstein set is non measurable.

Proof: Suppose a Bernstein set $B$  is measurable. Then $B$ and $B^c$ both are null sets (complement of a Bernstein set is also Bernstein). This implies the whole space has measure $0$! (contradiction).